# Can two DDEV Laravel projects share a single database?

Tags: laravel, docker, ddev

I have 2 separate Laravel projects configured to use a common database.

Reasons are mostly related to separating concerns:

- project A is related to handling the core tables via REST APIs;
- project B reads the core tables and operates on another set of tables by using jobs/queues/etc...

I'm using DDEV for local environment and I'm struggling to find a solution to share a single db instance between the two projects.
**I want to be able to run `ddev start` from project A OR project B and have a single reference for the db container, as well as run both projects together at the same time.**

Is that even possible with DDEV, maybe with a docker-compose.db-override.yaml on project B?

Other SO questions didn't help me that much... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to do and is documented in the [DDEV FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/faq/#can-different-projects-communicate-with-each-other):

> Yes, this is commonly required for situations like Drupal migrations. For the `web` container to access the `db` container of another project, use `ddev-<projectname>-db` as the hostname of the other project.

> Let’s say we have two projects, for example: project A, and project B. In project A, use `mysql -h ddev-projectb-db` to access the database server of project B.

Comment: This is not an answer for my problem, this is just a way to open a mysql shell on the other project's DB. I need to set up Project A to actually run on the Project B database. I'm asking for a set of `ddev` commands or a ddev sample configuration in order to achieve this. thank you

Comment: moreover, this is not an answer too because I asked specifically to have Project A pointing to a Project B database without the need to run the entire Project B (web+db+router). What's the point in giving me a downvote for my question?

Comment: Neither I nor you know who downvoted your question, except that I know it wasn't me. Be nice to people that take the time to interact with you.

If you want project A to use project B's database, you just change project A's settings to point to project B (ddev-projectb-db, port 3306 for example). The example use of the `mysql` client is just an example of the communication technique.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to be offensive, but there are no real examples on how to configure this and I got frustrated after an entire afternoon with no success. btw, can you please share a sample ddev config to achieve that? I should use an overrride, am I right? otherwise ddev automatically reverts its own config files

Comment: You're being unkind to the wrong person. This is the person who is trying to help you. Please stay on topic.

Comment: DDEV can create and manage settings files for some types of projects, but this is completely configurable. It does not do so for Laravel I don't think, you're responsible for your own settings files I believe. So point them at the right project. But please read https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/cms-settings/